# По причине ошибки Webpack невозможно запустить вновь созданное приложение React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, webpack

Создал приложение React при помощи yarn create react-app.
При попытке запуска yarn start выдает ошибку:

Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.cache.cacheDirectory: The provided value "C:\(здесь путь)\node_modules\.cache" contains
  exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
  -> Base directory for the cache (defaults to node_modules/.cache/webpack).
- configuration.module.rules[1].oneOf[3].include: The provided value "C:\(путь)\src" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
- configuration.output.path: The provided value "C:\(путь)\build" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
  -> The output directory as **absolute path** (required).

Что за ерунда? Почему возникает? Как лечить?

Comment: "(здесь путь)" - какой конкретно путь?

Comment: пусть от корня С: до папки с проектом. Окончание пути кстати сохранено.

Comment: Какой КОНКРЕТНО путь?

Comment: ну например вот такой C:\\Users\\User\\Dev\\Projects\\codes\\front\\node_modules\\.cache

Comment: Меня интересует не "например", а конкретный настоящий путь, потому что ошибка ругается именно на конкретный настоящий путь, а не на ваше "например"

Comment: Ну и собственно "Почему возникает" написано прямо в тексте этой ошибки

Comment: Это конкретный путь.

Comment: Ошибка ругается на восклицательный знак, а в показанном вами пути нету восклицательного знака. Что-то тут нечисто

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. Он действительно ругался на путь в котором был восклицательный знак в названии папки. Я не понял что он на путь ругается.
Еще раз спасибо.

Comment: @andreymal было кстати несколько десятков просмотров вопроса. Только ты понял что он на путь ругается. :) Спасибо.